# How to convert a link into seo friendly link?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have a sample link and i.e - `http://localhost/project1/type.php?country=The_South-Korea`

So I want to beautify this as SEO friendly link - `http://localhost/project1/type/The_South-Korea`

I have used this code snippet to change it but it is not working :

```
RewriteRule ^type/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) type.php?country=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now, what should be the correct code to get the country value...

Sorry answers are posted but still not working for me.

Note: Not working means if `$_GET['country']` is used it's not getting the value, saying not defined.

Comment: Not working in which way? Internal server error? Or 404? Or type.php is called, but the `country` parameter is missing? Or...?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to modify your rule.  Note that `^` refers to the beginning of the query.  Not sure if you need to include `http://localhost`.  But I think you at least need to include the beginning of the query, i.e. `/project1/`.

I have not tested this answer, but something more like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/project1/type/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) type.php?country=$1 [NC,L]
```

Check the [Apache manual for your version of Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/) for more details.